# If a thread that is blocked on a std::condition_variable is notified, but the lock on the associated mutex has not been released what would be result?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, mutex, condition-variable

Is it clear what would happen if a thread blocked on a std::condition_variable receives a notification but the lock on the associated mutex is not yet released, and the lock will be released 10 seconds later? Would the thread wait for the lock to be released or is the situation undefined?
I added a 15seconds sleep on purpose to make the lock unavailable during that time to see how waiting thread will be doing. It is doing OK but just wanted to be sure about it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

struct SharedResource
{
    SharedResource() :
        cv_mutex(), cv(), counter(0)
    {

    }

    /*
    This mutex is used for three purposes:
    1) to synchronize accesses to counter
    2) to synchronize accesses to std::cerr
    3) for the condition variable cv
    */
    std::mutex cv_mutex;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    int counter;
};

void waits(SharedResource& sharedRes)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(sharedRes.cv_mutex);
    std::cerr << "Waiting... \n";
    while (sharedRes.counter != 1) 
    {
        sharedRes.cv.wait_for(lk,3s);
        std::cerr << "Thread ID: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " wakes up every 3 seconds.\n";
    }
    std::cerr << "...finished waiting." << "counter: " << sharedRes.counter << std::endl;
} //The lk object will be unlocked after this scope ends.

void signals(SharedResource& sharedRes)
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(sharedRes.cv_mutex);
        std::cerr << "Notifying...\n";
    } // The lk object will be unlocked after this scope ends.
    sharedRes.cv.notify_all();

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(6));

    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(sharedRes.cv_mutex);
        sharedRes.counter = 1;
        std::cerr << "Notifying again...\n";
    
    sharedRes.cv.notify_all();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(15));

    }// The lk object will be unlocked after this scope ends.
}

int main()
{
    SharedResource sharedRes;

    std::thread
        t1(waits, std::ref(sharedRes)),
        t2(signals, std::ref(sharedRes));
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

Comment: The sleeping thread won't run until it successfully got the lock again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If a thread that is blocked on a `std::condition_variable` is notified, but the lock on the associated `mutex` has not been released what would be result?

It will continue to `wait` / `wait_for` until it can reacquire the lock.

When `std::condition_variable::wait` and `wait_for` returns (for whatever reason), the lock is held again, so you don't have to worry about that.

It can even return from `wait` without having gotten any notifications (spurious wake-ups) - but, no matter what, the lock is reacquired when the call returns.

Comment: If I remember correctly then condition_variables can spuriously wakeup, so always use wait/wait_for with a predicate. This way the condition variable will resume waiting if condition is still not met.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Yes spurious wake-ups are real (as I mentioned in the answer) but even if that's the reason for the `wait` to return, the lock is held when it does return.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Would you please clarify this more. I am a bit confused by the following statement? what do you mean by 'return' in this context?

"When std::condition_variable::wait and wait_for returns (for whatever reason), the lock is held again, so you don't have to worry about that. "

" ... but, no matter what, the lock is reacquired when the call returns."

Comment: @Sam It simply means that when you call `cv.wait` or `cv.wait_for`, it will "hang" and when it returns from hanging, the lock has been reacquired .

Comment: @Sam Is there anything else you'd like me to clarify btw? Any part left unanswered?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks for asking. Just a quick clarification: when a thread is waiting for a lock and even notification is sent but the associated lock hasn't yet released, the thread won't go to th next line , right? it won't print that message in the example above, right?      it stays at this line even if it is timedout?  sharedRes.cv.wait_for(lk,3s);

Comment: @Sam Yes. From cppreference: _"Atomically releases `lock`, blocks the current executing thread, and adds it to the list of threads waiting on `*this`. The thread will be unblocked when `notify_all()` or `notify_one()` is executed, or when the relative timeout `rel_time` expires. It may also be unblocked spuriously. When unblocked, regardless of the reason, `lock` is reacquired and `wait_for()` exits."_ - so when notified, it'll just hang on trying to `lock` (or `try_lock` in the background somehow), which will not succeed until the thread holding the lock releases it.

Comment: Appreciate that. Thank you.